# Calculating Kappa correlation coefficients of the data to find agreement between two raters

Tags: r, kappa

I am trying to calculate Kappa correlation coefficients of following data to find agreement between two raters. However, from the data set, I can see that the raters are agreeing on almost all the incidences except one. But I am getting Kappa as zero. (Kappa as zero in my understanding is raters are not agreeing. Source: [Link](http://www.statisticshowto.com/cohens-kappa-statistic/))

Could someone please help me here?

```
icc(mean_d, model = "one", type = "agreement", conf.level=0.95)

rater1  rater2
7   7
7   7
7   7
7   7
7   7
7   7
7   7
7   7
7   7
7   7
7   7
7   7
7   7
7   7
7   7
7   7
7   7
7   7
7   7
7   7
7   7
7   7
7   7
7   7
7   7
7   7
7   7
7   7
7   0
7   7
7   7
7   7
7   7
7   7
7   7
7   7
7   7
7   7
7   7
```

PS: I have the question posted [HERE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/351451/calculating-kappa-correlation-coefficients-of-the-data-to-find-agreement-between), However, I am not getting any answer. Thank you.